# How to exclude date patterns while crawling Amazon S3 folders. using aws crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have folder structure like:

```
s3://foo/table1/2021-06-12/03-35-00/
s3://foo/table1/Current/data
s3://foo/table2/2021-06-12/03-35-00/
s3://foo/table2/Current/data
s3://foo/table3/2021-06-12/03-35-00/
s3://foo/table3/Current/data
```

... so on

I want to exclude all date and timestamps pattern and only crawl Current/data folders. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: What is the "include path" in crawler settings ?

Comment: I just want to crawl folders Current/data under all tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your current crawler *include path* is set to crawl `s3://foo` location, then you can use ***Exclude patterns*** configuration in crawler settings
like this : `s3://foo/tabel*/2021*/**` which will skip all files and folders for all tabels if starting with date 2021...

Similarly you can add other ***glob patterns*** in this section to skip other files and folders.

[image]

For better understanding you can refer *include and exclude patterns* section [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html)